# inserting column headings into hsqldb text file

Tags: java, csv, hsqldb

I'm modifying someone else's Java code, learning Java as I go. :-). I'm writing hsqldb TEXT files, and I would like the final files to have a 'heading' row, so that they can be more easily understood as plain text. hsqldb has a switch 'ignore_first=true' for reading such files, but I can't find a way to write the line in. It may not exist, but there is a tantalizing reference to SOURCE HEADER in the documentation. Does anyone know how to use it?
Here is a simplified sample of what I have tried:

```
    String createtextTable =  
        "CREATE TEXT TABLE MolSet (" +
            " id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY," +
            " filename VARCHAR(300)," +
            " expSolFilename VARCHAR(300)," +
            " variance DOUBLE" +  ");" ;

    String headingsTable = "id,filename,expSolFilename, variance";

    try
    {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        stmt.execute(createtextTable);
        setTableStmt = "SET TABLE " + “MolSet” + " SOURCE " +
            '"' + TABLES[0] + ".csv;ignore_first=true" + '"';
        stmt.execute(setTableStmt);

        headingStmt = "SET TABLE " + “MolSet” + " SOURCE HEADER " +
            '"' + headingsTable + '"';
        stmt.execute(headingStmt);
    }
    catch( SQLException sqle )
    {
        return false;
    }


    return true;
}
```

this gives sql error:
Invalid TEXT table source string in statement [SET TABLE MolSet SOURCE HEADER]

I hope you can help, even if it is to confirm it is impossible. Thanks,
Jocelyn

Answer (score 0):

The source and source header strings must be enclosed in single quotes:

```
  SET TABLE MolSet SOURCE HEADER 'id,filename,expSolFilename,variance'
```

You have used double quotes instead.

Edit: The answer is for the latest version. Older versions since 1.8.x support this, but may require double quotes. The number of columns in the header and table must match. Alternatively, you can edit the text source while the database is offline and add the headers yourself.

Comment: Thanks, tried changing to single quotes - got the same error message.
In the discussion at sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/discussion/73674/thread/4a01f5f9 where someone asked a similar question, (without satisfactory answer) the answers used double quotes.
 Jocelyn

Comment: Two weeks since I asked, and the only answer is not true. I guess that means it is not possible.    Or possibly I need to install the latest hsqldb, instead of the one packaged with my program, but that's got its own problems

Answer (score 0):

This SQL file works for making CSV text files from a table and also sets field headers.  It is specific for HSQLDB (version 1.8.1.3).

Website for database DL and docs is HSQLDB.ORG

I hope it helps.

```
-- ========================
-- MAKE TABLE TEXT_TABLE_01
-- ========================

DROP TABLE TEXT_TABLE_01 IF EXISTS;

CREATE TEXT TABLE TEXT_TABLE_01
    ( ID_NUMBER  INTEGER
    , FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(30)
    , LAST_NAME  VARCHAR(30)
    , DEAR_      VARCHAR(50)
    )
;

SET TABLE TEXT_TABLE_01 SOURCE "TEXT_TABLE_01.TXT;ignore_first=true;fs=:";
SET TABLE TEXT_TABLE_01 SOURCE HEADER "ID_NUMBER:FIRST_NAME:LAST_NAME:DEAR_";


INSERT INTO TEXT_TABLE_01
        ( ID_NUMBER, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, DEAR_ )
    SELECT
          ID_NUMBER, FIRST_NAME, SURNAME,   DEAR_
    FROM
        TMP_NON_PERSONAL
;

SELECT * FROM TEXT_TABLE_01;

SET TABLE TEXT_TABLE_01 SOURCE OFF;

-- DELETE ALL TEXT FILES WHEN FINISHED ... OR BEFORE STARTING ...
```